# Reducing Lag from Garbage Collection on JS Parallax Effect in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, garbage-collection

I've implemented a simple parallax effect based on this tutorial:

[A Simple Parallax Scrolling Technique](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641)

It worked but it was pretty jagged/choppy on Safari and mildly choppy on Firefox so I tried debouncing the scroll events with the help of this tutorial:

[Leaner, Meaner, Faster Animations with requestAnimationFrame](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/)

It worked swimmingly on Safari to create smooth scrolling but now I'm seeing some slightly worse lag/choppiness on Firefox.  I think it's tide to garbage collection.

[image: Firefox Performance]

I've looked at many other answers on here for reducing garbage collection but their typically dealing with huge animations/games and talk about pooling objects which I don't think applies in this simple case.  I've seen a couple mention event handlers causing issues and that I need to clear variables to free up memory but I'm not sure how that applies.

Is there a way to optimize this code so Firefox isn't lagging?

Any help is much appreciated!

Checkout the working page [here](http://markpfaff.com/template/index.php)

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){                           

    /*begin parallax effect*/                         

    /** start with smooth scrolling by  
     http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/
    */             
        lastScrollY     = 0,
        ticking         = false;

    /* Callback for our scroll event - just
     * keeps track of the last scroll value
     */
    function onScroll() {
        lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
        requestTick();
    }

    /** smooth scrolling
     * Calls rAF if it's not already
     * been done already
     */
    function requestTick() {
        if(!ticking) {
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
            ticking = true;
        }
    }


    var $bgobj = $('section[data-type="background"]'); // assigning the object
    var $window = $(window); 
    function update() {
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

        // allow further rAFs to be called
        ticking = false;

    } 

       // only listen for scroll events
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);

    // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })(); 

});
```

HTML (just the pertinent elements)

```
<body class="parallax">
    <section id="parallax-wrapper" class="parallax-back pages" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <--! all the page content-->
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;  
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative; 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;   
}

#parallax-wrapper {
    background:url(../images/backgroundtsm.png) 50% 0 repeat fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 2200px; 
    height: 2200px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    position: relative;
}
```